# How to merge the pdf files from all subdirectories?

Tags: pdf

I want to use `pdftk` to merge all pdffiles in a directory *and* all of its subdirectories. I cannot find a --recursive option in the man pages.

Doing this manually (using a GUI) is not an option as it would be too much work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is ideal, but you could:

1. cp all the pdf files of the subdirectories into one directory.

   ```
   mkdir all-in-one
   find SomeDirectory -iname '*.pdf' -exec cp {} all-in-one/
   ```
2. concatenate them

   ```
   cd all-in-one
   pdftk *.pdf output output.pdf
   ```

The disadvantage of this solution is that you have to copy all the files.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't like file names that include spaces, but it seemed to work for a couple files in two different directories.  That is a back quote (same key as the tilde character) surrounding the find|xargs pipeline.

pdftk `find . -name *.pdf -print|xargs echo` cat output out.pdf